# If $M$ is a finitely generated module and the quotient $M/T(M)$ by its torsion module $T(M)$ is projective, then $T(M)$ is also finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $T(M)$ be its torsion module. $M$ is finitely generated and $M/T(M)$ is projective. Without any further assumption on $R$, show that $T(M)$ is finitely generated.

The second condition seems to be a bit weird. I don't understand why it has to be projective. Does it mean we can use cohomological tools to solve it?

Comment: If $M/T(M)$ is projective, then you can write $M\cong T(M)\oplus (M/T(M))$, so that $T(M)$ is a homomorphic image of $M$.

Comment: To be more explicit, $0\to T(M)\to M\to M/T(M)\to 0$ splits when $M/T(M)$ is projective: since $M\to M/T(M)$ is surjective, we can lift the identity map on $M/T(M)$ through $M\to M/T(M)$ to get a section $M/T(M)\to M$.

Comment: It's so much more clear now! Thank you!@KenanskiBowspleefi